# Perform math opeartion with two Numpy array - limit the number

Tags: numpy

I have 2 Numpy arrays which I need to perform some basic math operations on them.
But also I can't have the result of this operation to be greater than 255, due to the type (`uint8`) of the final numpy array (named `magnitude`). Any Idea? Except of traversing through the array...

```
# Notice that the data type is "np.uint8", also arrays are 2D
magnitude = np.zeros((org_im_width,org_im_height), dtype=np.uint8)

# "numpy_arr_1" and "numpy_arr_2" both of the same size & type as "magnitude"

# In the following operation, I should limit the number to 255
magnitude = ( (np.int_(numpy_arr_1))**2 + (np.int_(numpy_arr_2))**2 )**0.5

# The following doesn't work obviously:
# magnitude = min(255,((np.int_(numpy_arr_1))**2+(np.int_(numpy_arr_2))**2)**0.5)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if you assign `magnitude = ...` after its creation, you are replacing the initial uint8 array by the obtianed in the operation, so magnitude wont be uint8 anymore.

Anyway, in case is just a mistake in the example, to perform what you want you can either `clamp/clip` or `normalize` the values of the resulting operations:

You can find [np.clip](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html) which limits the values of an array to a `min` and `max` values:

```
>>> magnitude = np.clip(operation, 0, 255)
```

Where operation is the magnitude you calculate. In fact, what you might want is:

```
>>> magnitude = np.clip(np.sqrt(a**2 + b**2), 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)
```

Where `a` and `b` are your `np.int_(numpy_arr_1)` and `np.int_(numpy_arr_2)` respectively, renamed for readability purposes.

Additionally, as in your case all the values are positive, you can replace `np.clip` by `np.minimum`:

```
>>> magnitude = np.minimum(np.sqrt(a**2 + b**2), 255).astype(np.uint8)
```

However, this just limits the magnitude of the vector to 255 (what you want), but you will lose a lot of information for `points` of higher magnitude. If the magnitude at some point is 1000 it will be clamped to 255, and therefore in your final array `1000 = 255`. Two points with a wide variation in magnitude will end up having the same magnitude (1000 and 255 in this case).

To avoid this, you can [normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_(image_processing)) (re-scale) your range of magnitudes to `[0, 255]`. This means, if in your initial computation the magnitude array is in the ranges `[0, 1000]`, transform it to `[0, 255]` so `1000` before will be `255` after, but `255` before will now be `63` (simple linear scaling).

```
>>> tmp = np.sqrt(a**2 + b**2).astype(float)
>>> magnitude = (tmp / tmp.max() * 255).astype(np.uint8)
```

`tmp / tmp.max()` will rescale all the values to `[0, 1]` range (if the array is float), and by multiplying by 255 the array is reescaled to `[0, 255]` again.

In case your magnitude's lower range is not `0`, you can perform a [re-scale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_(image_processing)) from say `[200, 1000]` to `[0, 255]` that better represents your data:

```
>>> tmp = np.sqrt(a**2 + b**2).astype(float)
>>> tmax, tmin = tmp.max(), tmp.min()
>>> magnitude = ((tmp - tmin) / (tmax - tmin) * 255).astype(np.uint8)
```

Comment: 1. Why did you choose to use `np.sqrt` instead of `**0.5`?
2. Regarding the information loss - I understand - my goal is that the data that's in the Numpy array will eventually be a `uint8`, while neglecting the info loss.
3. I **must not** perform linear scaling! It will change the other values, which aren't higher than 255.

My goal is to perform that math operation, and to make sure that **only** the values which exceed 255 - will be changed to 255. This is because that my final Numpy array should contain data that its type is `uint8`.

Thanks!

Comment: `np.sqrt` and `**0.5` do the same and both are valid. I just prefer `np.sqrt` because is more readable. As I didn't know the final goal of your operation, I was trying to show all the possible options. `np.minimum` should work for you then.

Comment: This won't work: if `a` and `b` are of dtype `uint8`, when you do `a**2 + b**2`, any result exceeding `255` will overflow and only the LSB bits will be kept, e.g. if you have `a = np.array([15, 17], dtype=np.uint8)` then `a**2` evaluates to `array([225,  33], dtype=uint8)`, where `33 = 17*17 % 256`. So the clipping you correctly explained has no effect, unless the original arrays are converted, e.g. to `float` dtype, before doing the operations.

Comment: Well, in that case you only need to cast `a` and `b` to `int` as the OP did in the question. I've just assumed that. Edited to clarify.